# Getting Mac Hazel to e-mail .lnk, doc, and .xls files to my evernote account

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, email

i'm trying to automate and simplify my life. I'm new to hazel and apple scripts..

I have a lot of documents and i pull a lot of things of the web. i simply drag the link to my desktop where it makes a .lnk file.

i want to create a hazel + apple script that will look for these .lnk files and send an email with the link file attached to my evernote email address.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In Hazel Create a new rule.

**If all ..**

1,  Extension - is - *ink*

**Do the following:**

2, Run AppleScript - *embedded script*.

Click the info icon to edit the script. Paste this script into it. With the correct email addresses, subject, content set.

```
set theAttachment1 to (POSIX path of theFile)
set subject_ to "subject"
set the_content to "the_content"
tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:subject_, content:the_content & return & return}
    tell newMessage

        set visible to false
        set sender to "my1@mac.com"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"their@mac.com"}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1} at after the last paragraph

        (* change save to send to send*)
        send --<<<<---------------- change save to send to send or send to save to save to drafts
        (* change save to send to send*)
    end tell
end tell
```

3, Add a second action to move the file to a folder.  If not you may keep getting the same files sent over and over again.

[image]

Comment: How would I tell Mail to quit after? I tried `tell application "Mail quit end tell` but it creates a loop where the file keeps getting emailed, but never moved to the new folder. Thanks!